# Is it OK to ask for suggestions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've been wondering if it is ok to post game suggestions for specific genre ?

Basically, I want to ask what kind of games I could play with a friend. But I'm unsure if that's really a question to be answered because it could have no real definitive answer. I'm only looking for ideas here, and not a "real" answer.

I don't want to pollute Arqade with low quality question, so I wonder.

Thank you!

Comment: Just as a side note, thank you for asking this in meta before asking an off-topic question. We get a lot of users here who don't bother reading our rules and ask off-topic questions. Asking before hand is appreciated and noted.

Comment: A quick look through the [help/on-topic] page would've answered this question before it was asked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't ask questions asking for game recommendations on the main site. They are expressly off topic. We have a specific close reason for it.

Feel free to stop by [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), however, where discussing games is a thing we very occasionally have time for in between all the memes.

Comment: Also a place worth visiting if you have a Reddit account: https://www.reddit.com/r/gamingsuggestions/ Reddit, being a discussion forum, is a lot more accepting of questions like this.